# laravel 5 ide autocompletion

Tags: autocomplete, laravel-5, phpstorm

I want to switch to laravel 5, but have some trouble with ide - autocompletion. I'm using phpstorm.
In google, the answers always end up with suggesting to use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper . But it seems like it is broken for Laravel 5.

The steps I am doing are:

1. Install Laravel 5

   ```
   composer create-project laravel/laravel
   ```
2. Require ide-helper

   ```
   composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
   ```
3. Added 'Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider',

   ```
   ....
   'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
   'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
   'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
   'Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider',
   ```
4. Trying to generate the helper file

   ```
   artisan ide-helper:generate
   ```

But it always breaks with following error:

```
exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'There are no commands defined in the "ide-helper" namespace.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:501

0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php(535): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->findNamespace('ide-helper')
1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console

\Application.php(192): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find('ide-helper:gene...')
2 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php(126): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Outpu
t\ConsoleOutput))
3 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(91): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Out
put\ConsoleOutput))
4 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
5 {main}
```

Maybe someone had the same issue and can help me.
I'm open for different solutions for autocompletion other than barryvdh's ide-helper.

Comment: Have you done **ALL** steps? I mean this one: *"After updating composer, add the ServiceProvider to the providers array in config/app.php"* ?

Comment: yes, i've added the service provider, will update my question. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem and this fixed it:

Before you run `php artisan ide-helper:generate` command, make sure to `php artisan clear-compiled` and `php artisan optimize` as it's noted [here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper#user-content-automatic-phpdoc-generation-for-laravel-facades). If this didn't fixed your problem, take a look at [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/cleaning-system-cache.html) and clean out PhpStorm cache by choosing this:

> File | Invalidate Caches/Restart

After auto restarting, PhpStorm will index again and everything should work fine.

Sorry for my bad english.

Edited: After these steps import your Facades like this `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth` link them inside your `_ide_helper.php` file like `use Auth`.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem. These are the steps I took to fix it:

- I double-checked that `'Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider'` was correctly added to the `providers` array in `config/app.php`.
- I executed `artisan clear-compiled`. Had no effect

Executing `php artisan config:clear` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This error occur when the package ServiceProvider isn't loaded.

If you have multiple config file (like for different environment), you must ensure that the service provider is well set in all the environment you which to use the package.

```
config/
  local/
    app.php
  app.php
```

to verify if the service provider is correctly set to your application you can dump the app config:

```
dd(\Config::get('app.providers'));
```

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with what was asked.

Comment: @RossEdman Seems like it does. If 'Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider' isn't added to the providers array in app.php, then artisan won't show any commands from the ide-helper namespace. The question mentions that he did this step, but I see in the comments that he edited is question to add that information. This is a good answer to the original question that was likely to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
php artisan ide-helper:generate
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an [updated gist](https://gist.github.com/jewei/369cee0f859fafab3db9) as of this month. I have tested this and it works in PHPStorm.

Also you don't have to install this through composer. Copy the gist and save it in your root folder as `_ide_helper.php`.