# Phpstorm Error: [InvalidArgumentException] No hint path defined for [ide-helper]

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want  PhpStorm to have code completion support and syntax highlighting for many of Laravel’s facades. So i followed these steps in 
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper.
  i also followed : [laravel 5 ide autocompletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498195/laravel-5-ide-autocompletion)
  But i keep getting [InvalidArgumentException]   No hint path defined for [ide-helper].
What might be the problem?

Comment: Did you run `composer dumpautoload` after installing the package?

Comment: @aynber no i didnt. i just did but it is still giving the same error